# More question on the proof of orbit-stabilizer theorem from Gowers's weblog

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions

Still I'm reading [Gowers's weblog about orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/group-actions-ii-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem/), I must admit that my understanding of this materiel improved, but still I have some question.

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $X$ be a finite $G$-set. We define the following sets:

$$S_x = \left\{ g\in G: gx=x\right\};$$

$$S_{xy} = \left\{g\in G:gx=y \right\}.$$

In second proof that Gowers presents, he explains that picking $h$ from $S_{xy}$ isn't so simple, since there is no *canonical choice*. Then he states the following statement:

> If you can’t make a canonical choice, then make all choices at once.

And defines the next map:

$$\phi: S_{xy}\times S_x \to S_{xy},$$
$$(h,g)\mapsto hg .$$

**My first question is:**

Why is $\phi$ well defined?

**My second question:**

- Why is $\phi$ clearly not bijective?

His, and our purpose is to prove that $|S_{xy}|=|S_{x}|$. To do that, we wish to show that every element of $S_{xy}$ has exactly $|S_{xy}|$ preimages under $\phi$. That is, for every $u\in S_{xy}$:

$$|\phi^{-1}(u)|=|\{(h,g):hg=u\}|=|S_{xy}|$$

**My third question:**

How does one deduce from this that $|S_{xy}||S_x|=|S_{xy}|^2$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: @First question: Just check that if $h \in S_{xy}$ and $g \in S_x$, then $hg \in S_{xy}$.

Comment: @Second question: No, it fails to be injective (in general).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thank you, but how you show that it fails to be injective? How to show $h_1g_1=h_2g_2$ not implies $h_1=h_2$ and $g_1=g_2$?

Comment: For example, the domain of $\phi$ is larger than the target if $S_x$ is not the trivial group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered your first and second questions in the comments. Let me answer
the third question:

We have

$S_{xy}\times S_{x}=\bigcup_{u\in S_{xy}}\phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)  $,

and the union is a disjoint union (i.e., the sets $\phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)
$ for $u\in S_{xy}$ are pairwise disjoint). Thus,

**(1)** $\left\vert S_{xy}\times S_{x}\right\vert =\sum_{u\in S_{xy}
}\left\vert \phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)  \right\vert $.

We shall now show that

**(2)** $\left\vert \phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)  \right\vert =\left\vert
S_{xy}\right\vert $ for every $u\in S_{xy}$.

*Proof of **(2)**.* Fix $u\in S_{xy}$. Then,

$\phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)  =\left\{  \left(  h,g\right)  \in S_{xy}\times
S_{x}\ :\ \underbrace{\phi\left(  \left(  h,g\right)  \right)  }
_{=hg}=u\right\}  $

$=\left\{  \left(  h,g\right)  \in S_{xy}\times S_{x}\ :\ hg=u\right\}  $.

Hence,

$\left\vert \phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)  \right\vert =\left\vert \left\{
\left(  h,g\right)  \in S_{xy}\times S_{x}\ :\ hg=u\right\}  \right\vert $.

Now, how many elements $\left(  h,g\right)  \in S_{xy}\times S_{x}$ satisfy
$hg=u$ ? It is easy to see that, for every $h\in S_{xy}$, there exists exactly
one $g\in S_{x}$ satisfying $hg=u$ (namely, $g=h^{-1}u$; of course, you need
to check that $h^{-1}u$ is actually a element of $S_{x}$). Therefore, for
every $h\in S_{xy}$, we have $\left\vert \left\{  g\in S_{x}\ :\ hg=u\right\}
\right\vert =1$. Now,

$\left\vert \phi^{-1}\left(  u\right)  \right\vert =\left\vert \left\{
\left(  h,g\right)  \in S_{xy}\times S_{x}\ :\ hg=u\right\}  \right\vert $

$=\sum_{h\in S_{xy}}\underbrace{\left\vert \left\{  g\in S_{x}
\ :\ hg=u\right\}  \right\vert }_{=1}=\sum_{h\in S_{xy}}1=\left\vert
S_{xy}\right\vert $.

This proves **(2)**.

Now,

$\left\vert S_{xy}\right\vert \cdot\left\vert S_{x}\right\vert =\left\vert
S_{xy}\times S_{x}\right\vert =\sum_{u\in S_{xy}}\left\vert \phi^{-1}\left(
u\right)  \right\vert $ (by **(1)**)

$=\sum_{u\in S_{xy}}\left\vert S_{xy}\right\vert $ (by **(2)**)

$=\left\vert S_{xy}\right\vert \cdot\left\vert S_{xy}\right\vert $.

Since $\left\vert S_{xy}\right\vert $ is nonzero, we can cancel $\left\vert
S_{xy}\right\vert $ out of this equation and obtain $\left\vert S_{x}
\right\vert =\left\vert S_{xy}\right\vert $.

Comment: +1, Many things are more clear to me now with your answer. I will accept it soon enough, when I completely understand it.